# Best way to run test queries in python: bash vs default shell

Tags: python, bash, shell

I'm new to django and python and am trying to determine the best way to 'play around' with querying (I come from a front-end background and am used to using `console.log` there, but cannot at the back-end).

If I run `python3 manage.py shell`, I can then run useful commands in that shell, for example, I can test querying `Tracking` objects:

```
from myapp.tracking.models import Tracking
trackings = Tracking.objects.all()
print(trackings)
```

However, in my setup I apparently need to run a shell inside docker:

`sudo docker-compose exec myapp bash`

Here I can't run commands like `from myapp.tracking.models import Tracking` as I get errors like `bash: from: command not found`. From googling around, I assume that bash is a different type of shell to whatever the `python manage.py shell` shell uses (Ipython?).

So my question is how can I use the same shell that the `python3 manage.py shell` command uses? Presumably running something like `sudo docker-compose exec myapp SOME_OTHER_SHELL`? And if this is not possible, am I correct in assuming that bash is just a different type of shell with a different syntax for importing and querying variables? If so, any useful links to docs would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Who or what is forcing you to use `exec myapp bash`, instead of `exec myapp python3 manage.py shell`?

Comment: Mind, if you are in a `bash` shell, you can _from there_ run `python3 manage.py shell` to invoke the django shell as a subprocess (after you `cd`'d to the directory that has `manage.py` in it; to avoid the need for that, make sure your Dockerfile already sets that as current working directory).

Comment: ...bash is a completely different programming language; you can't load a Python module in a bash shell, just as you can't run bash code with a Python interpreter -- you need to start a Python interpreter _from bash_ before you can run Python code, and same in the other direction (if you're in a Python interpreter and you want to run bash code, you need to start a bash interpreter to run it in).

Comment: As it is, though, right now this question doesn't really provide the level of specificity that would be needed to provide a fully tested, guaranteed-to-work answer (for example, the `python3 manage.py shell` above assuming that your current working directory is set right, but without seeing your Dockerfile we don't know what "right" is, or whether you're setting it). A [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: thank you @CharlesDuffy - the `exec myapp python3 manage.py shell` command was what I was looking for! Useful info to know